# How to process Json using jquery /javascript

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, grails

Hi my setDefaultPoint controller returns map as a json... the code is below

```
def setDefaultPoint = {
    if (springSecurityService.isLoggedIn()) {
        def officeId = params.officeId          
        def officeRoleInstance=OfficeRole.get(officeId)
        def company= officeRoleInstance.company
        def defaultPoint = officeRoleInstance.distanceChart.officePoint
        def map = [defaultPoint:defaultPoint]
        map << [company:company]
        def json = map as JSON
        render json
    }
```

the ajax call which sends to request to this controller is

```
function setDefaultPoint(){
        var officeId =  $('#clientTrip_officeId').val();

        $.ajax({
            url:"${createLink(controller:'clientTrip',action:'setDefaultPoint')}",
            dataType: "json",
            data:({officeId: officeId}),
            success: function(data) {

                // here i want to get the id and name of default point and id and name of company...
        console.log('id of defaultpoint is---"+????) 
                    console.log('name of default point is---"+????)
                    console.log(id of company is-----------"+?????)        
            }

        }); 
    }
```

from json i am passing two different object.. so how to get the propirties of those object... both defaultPoint object and Company object has fields called id and anme

the response is looks like

```
 {"defaultPoint":{"class":"com.springpeople.steer.trips.Point","id":3,"name":"MG road"},"company":{"class":"com.springpeople.steer.partymodel.parties.Company","id":5,"addressPermanent":{"class":"Address","id":3},"contactDetails":null,"name":"Infosys","offices":[{"class":"OfficeRole","id":6}],"organizationRoles":[{"class":"OrganizationRole","id":5}],"panNumber":null,"serviceTaxNumber":null,"tanNumber":null}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the returned dataType is specified as `json`, the `data` argument passed to the function assigned to `success` will be the JavaScript object parsed from the returned json string, so long as the string is valid json. the `data` passed in the ajax call doesn't need the parens around it. This should work

```
function setDefaultPoint(){
    var officeId =  $('#clientTrip_officeId').val();

    $.ajax({
        url:"${createLink(controller:'clientTrip',action:'setDefaultPoint')}",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { officeId: officeId },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data.defaultPoint.id, data.defaultPoint.name);
            console.log(data.company.id, data.company.name);
        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
```

then  you can access things like `obj.class` and such.

**DOCUMENTATION:** http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: both default point object and company object has a fields called id and name how to get those

Comment: @Russ makes a good point, you don't need to parseJSON since the dataType is set as JSON. to access those fields, do this  `data.defaultPoint.id` and `data.company.id`

Answer (score 1):

if you have set `dataType: "json"`  you dont need to `parseJSON` simply in your success callback do

```
alert(data.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you have specified the dataType to be Json jQuery will parse the response into an object so you should be able to use:

```
function setDefaultPoint(){
        var officeId =  $('#clientTrip_officeId').val();

    $.ajax({
        url:"${createLink(controller:'clientTrip',action:'setDefaultPoint')}",
        dataType: "json",
        data:({officeId: officeId}),
        success: function(data) {

            // here i want to get the id and name of default point and id and name of company...
    console.log(data.defaultPoint.Id)         
        }

    }); 
}
```