# My pdo ajax code for search is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, pdo

What I want to do is: when a user types their email, my ajax code will run and show the user pass in the password inputbox.

The problem is that while my ajax code is sending the email to search.php, my search.php isn't giving the data to my ajax to show.

I think the problem is in my search.php because when i go to search.php after i type an email in my index the search.php is just blank no data is showing.

Index (Form):

```
email <input type="text" id="query" name="myemail" class="search_textbox" /><br />
Your Password <input type="text" id="mypass" name="mypass" readonly="readonly" /><br />
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.search_textbox').on('blur', function(){
                $('#query').change(updateTextboxes);
                updateTextboxes()  
            })
    $('.search_textbox').on('keydown', function(){
                $('#query').change(updateTextboxes); 
                updateTextboxes() 
            })
    $('#query').change(updateTextboxes);

    var  $mypass = $('#mypass');

    function updateTextboxes(){
        $.ajax({
        url:"search.php",
        type:"GET",
        data: { term : $('#query').val() },
        dataType:"JSON",
        success: function(result) {

        var ii = 1;

        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) { 
                    $mypass.val(result[i].value).show().trigger('input');                           
            ii++;
            }

        }


    });


};



});      
</script>
```

search.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$db = "test";

$dbc = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $host . ";dbname=" . $db, $user, $pass);
$dbc->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

if (isset($_GET['term'])) {

    $q = $_GET['term'];

    $sql = "SELECT password FROM students WHERE email = :term";
    $query = $dbc->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindParam(':term', $q);
    $results = $query->execute();

    $data = array();

    while ($row = $results->fetch()) {
        $data[] = array(
            'value' => $row['password'] 
        );
    }

    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($data);

}

?>
```

Comment: Try to `echo $_GET['term'];` to know whether you are getting the value from `index.php`.

Comment: @afaolek i tried it and it echo the email that i type in the index page

Comment: **3 things**. **first**: i would use `POST` instead of `GET`!, **second**: add a `print_r($result);` after execute and **third**: what do you think how many passwords one user have? i think just one so you don't really need a while loop. and `while` isn't needed anyway. if you expact more than one result, use `$results->fetchALL()`. Oh and `header('Content-type: application/json');` not needed

Comment: @Dwza i use while to fetch all and put all the values in an array and send it to ajax to show the password value in and inputbox if the user type his registered email.

Comment: The statement `$results = $query->execute();` returns a `bool`. Check [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php);

Comment: @Dwza im doing this so that if the user forgot his password he just need to type his registered email in the website and il make a function to send it to his email address his password.

Comment: Actually, it's not safe to store raw passwords. Try Binging [forgotpasswordphp](http://www.bing.com/search?q=forgot+password+implementation+php)

Comment: @afaolek il need it so that i can send his password to his email after typing his email to retrieve if he forgot his password.

Comment: don't save the password plain text. make a md5($password) befor saving to DB. if usere looses password, send him a link where he can set his password new. otherwise you will have a lot of unregistrations :D and you use `SELECT password FROM students WHERE email = 'foo@bar.de'`. first i hope email is a unique column :) this results exact 1 return value! so no while needed. and like i sayed befor, if you expact more values, use fetchALL

Comment: @Dwza `md5()` should ***not*** be used for passwords. It's so overused and easily broken. For PHP >= 5.5 you should use [`password_hash()`](http://us1.php.net/password_hash). For PHP > 5.37 but < 5.5 you should use [`bcrypt()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed `header('Content-type: application/json');`. I don't think it is necessary. Remove the line and try again. I am not sure but I think `php` `header` is needed for a new page. Since you have `echo json_encode($data);` and in your AJAX call, you are already processing the return data as `json`, the `header(...)` is not needed.

**EDIT**

```
$q = $_GET['term'];

$sql = "SELECT password FROM students WHERE email = :term";
$query = $dbc->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':term', $q);
if($query->execute() && $query->rowCount()){
    echo json_encode($query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));   
}
```

**SCRIPT**

```
function updateTextboxes(){
    $.ajax({
    url:"search.php",
    type:"GET",
    data: { term : $('#query').val() },
    dataType:"JSON",
    success: function(result) {
        //check here if you have a result, if yes than...
        $("#mypass").val(result.password);
    }
}
```

Comment: i got this error now "Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object "

Comment: I just noticed you were not properly processing the result as `json` in your `success` callback.  in a minute, I will update my answer to account for that.

Comment: Better still, read this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089368/how-to-process-json-using-jquery-javascript).

Comment: just wanted to make a post, but at the moment i wanted to start, you made an update :D could save a row if using `$results->rowCount()`direktly in the if. Like: `if($result)` or `if ($result->rowCount())`. don't know if the first one would work but i think.

Comment: @afaolek error in ur code "Fatal error: Call to a member function rowCount() on a non-object".

Comment: @afaolek i want to pass the value of the password to ajax to show it in the inputbox in index page.

Comment: @afaolek i use array cuz i want the real value of the password not a binary result

Comment: Found the error. Editing my answer again. There are comments in front of the edits.

Comment: @afaolek i saw the value of the password in search.php now but how come it doesnt show in inputbox in my index page? Is there wrong in my ajax script in receiving the value?

Comment: It's never a bad thing to specify a header like the one above. Technically, to be correct symantically, I believe you're supposed to pass along a header in the response.

Comment: Omitting the header will probably work in some cases. But adding a header has some benefit and will not cause any problems. So leave it in. If you don't have it you are technically sending the results as malformed html.